# how to select items in mysql based on their foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named `all_categories` and `all_words` that they are designed by this schema:

**all_categories table:**

```
create table all_categories(
    name varchar(20) not null default "others",
    primary key(name)
);
```

**all_words table:**

```
create table all_words(
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    english_word varchar(30),
    meaning varchar(100),
    full_english_meaning varchar(500) default null,
    primary key(id),
    category varchar(20) not null default "others",
    foreign key(category) 
        references all_categories(name)
        on delete cascade
);
```

as you see I have a foreign key in my `all_words` table that connects it to my `all_categories` table. In my app I want to make a query to retrieve my words by their categories in this jason form for example:

```
{
   medical_words:[epilepsy,...],
   political_words:[diplomacy,...],
   ...
}
```

what query should I write to get my words categorized by their categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
select w.category, group_concat(w.english_word) as words
from all_words w
group by w.category;
```

Normally, the category would have a numeric id and a `join` would be necessary to get the category name.  However, you are using the name for the foreign key reference, so you don't need `all_categories` in the query.